# How to fix property does not exist on '{}' with react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to make a **login state** globally for my **ReactJS** application with **typescript**.
I declared the context in a file and imported to App.tsx file.

```
export const loginContext = createContext({});
```

In the App.tsx file I created a state and provided the variable and the function as object.

```
import { loginContext } from "./context";

const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
return (
    <loginContext.Provider value={{ isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn }}>
    ...
    </loginContext.Provider>
)
```

Now I want to access the `isLoggedIn` variable in another file

I tried to do so by writing,

```
import { loginContext } from "../context";

const { isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn } = React.useContext(loginContext);
```

But **typescript** is showing me the following error,

> Property 'isLoggedIn' does not exist on type '{}'.

> Property 'setIsLoggedIn' does not exist on type '{}'.

*Any help would be appreciated*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define proper default values where you are creating the context. Something like this.

```
export const loginContext = createContext({
 isLoggedIn: false,
 setIsLoggedIn: (value: boolean): void => {}
});
```